# Django test unit logged in user

Tags: django, authentication, testing

I need some unit tests to check if a user after successful login can open profile editing page, how am I supposed to do this?

I tried this code, but it shows an error. Do I have to use my own view to register a user then to log in or there are some unit test modules for that?

```
class UserProfilePage(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.credentials = {
            'username': 'test_user',
            'password': 'secret'}
        user = User.objects.create_user(**self.credentials)

        self.user_profile = {
            'user': user,
            'first_name': 'Test_1',
            'surname': 'test_surname',
            'about_me': 'some_info',
            'email': 'test@anymail.com',
        }
                UserProfile.objects.create(**self.user_profile).save()
    self.user_id = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user.id)

    def test_profile_page_and_current_template(self):
        response = self.client.get('/blog/user/profile/', self.user_id)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

ValueError: Cannot query "Test_1": Must be "User" instance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The client API allows you to login a user like so:

```py
self.client.force_login(user)
```

Just run that before accessing the profile page in your test.

There also is an error in your code.

```py
...
self.user_id = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
...
```

Here you are assigning the profile object to `user_id` and later trying to pass `user_id` as parameter in the request, instead of the user ID. I am guessing that is why you get the error.

I would suggest to only set the `user` as object property; you do not need anything else. Then access it with `self.user.id` in your test.

See also: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.force_login